# ASP.NET with huge datatable use very high memory

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory-management

I just create the reporting project.

But I found problem that when I export the report that have many complex and very high record(1-10M record) , my server have very high load in memory(16GB+).

My process flow.
1. Use linq to sql to query database and store them in datatable.
2. then export datatable to excel with openxml.

I have been research some and found the solution that slice the datatable and export to several worksheet in excel.

But I think that isn't my true goal.
My question is how to solve datatable high memory issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to go for the `DataTable` in-between. Just stream data from the `IQueryable` directly into your OpenXML library (ie use a `foreach` on the Linq query result and push each row into your library, or write it manually).

If you do have to store it, use a proper class. `DataTable`s are stored internally as a list of arrays of `object`, thus boxing all value types (which affects performance and memory usage).